# Getting invalidCiphertextException: null when decrypting data which was encrypted with kms public key

Tags: node.js, encryption, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric, amazon-kms

I am building a POC based on asymmetric encryption where the public key from KMS will be downloaded and used on the client side to encrypt sensitive data and once that data is received at the server end it needs to be decrypted using KMS decrypt function.
Encryption and Decryption using KMS works fine but when I encrypt with the downloaded public key and then decrypt with KMS I get **invalidCiphertextException: null**

CMK Cryptographic Configuration is
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0muAb.png

**The code I use for encryption is**

```
var encrypt_with_public_key = function (data) {
    let fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),    
    absolutePath  = path.join(__dirname, 'Publickey.pem');   
    let publicKey = fs.readFileSync(absolutePath, "utf8");
    let encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt({
        key: Buffer.from(publicKey),        
        oaepHash: "sha256",
    },Buffer.from(data)).toString("base64");
       
    
    return encrypted;
}
```

**Code used for Decryption is**

```
var decrypt_data = function (data) {
    try {
        let params = {
            KeyId: kmsConfig["KeyId"], 
            EncryptionAlgorithm: kmsConfig["EncryptionAlgorithm"] /* RSAES_OAEP_SHA_256*/
        }
        params.CiphertextBlob = Buffer.from(data)        
        return kms.decrypt(params).promise().then(data => data.Plaintext);
        
    }
    catch (ex) {
        throw ex
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Did you check the expected data-type for CiphertextBlob? It may not need a buffer.